# I am building a python script to fill an sql database with a .csv file, and I keep getting an sql syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, cursor

I have a tabe called 'Tournage', but when I try to fill it with csv data using a cursor.execute I keep getting an sql syntax error. The syntax error is in this block of code:

```
sql_tournage = None
for Id in range(len(tournages)):
    entry = tournages[Id]
    if Id>0:
        sql_tournage = '{},({},{},{},{},{},{},{})'.format(sql_tournage, Id_Lieu, Date_de_debut, Date_de_fin, Localisation_de_la_scene, Code_Postal, Coordonnees_en_X, Coordonnees_en_Y)
    if Id<= 0:
        sql_tournage = '''INSERT INTO Tournage(Id_Lieu, Date_de_debut, Date_de_fin, Localisation_de_la_scene, Code_Postal, Coordonnees_en_X, Coordonnees_en_Y) VALUES{}'''.format(entry)
        sql_tournage = buffer_tournage.format(entry)
sql_tournage = '{};'.format(sql_tournage)
print(sql_tournage)
cursor.execute(sql_tournage)
```

Here is the whole file.

```
import csv
import mariadb
import sys
import datetime as datetime

try:
    film = mariadb.connect(
        host = "localhost",
        #port = ,
        user = "",
        password = "",
        database = "lieux_tournage_paris2"
    )

except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

cursor = film.cursor()
#create the MySql database

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Produire")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Realiser")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tourner")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Est_de_Type")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Production")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Type_Tournage")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Realisateur")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Producteur")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Lieu")
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tournage")
#These commands above are there to clear the database of any redundancies

create_table_tournage = '''CREATE TABLE Tournage(
   Id_Lieu VARCHAR(100),
   Date_de_debut DATE,
   Date_de_fin DATE,
   Localisation_de_la_scene VARCHAR(100),
   Code_Postal CHAR(5),
   Coordonnees_en_X DOUBLE,
   Coordonnees_en_Y DOUBLE,
   geo_shape VARCHAR(100),
   geo_point_2d VARCHAR(100),
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Lieu)
)'''
#   geo_shape VARCHAR(100),

#Id_Tournage INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
create_table_Type_Tournage = '''CREATE TABLE Type_Tournage(
   Id_Type INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Types_de_Tournage VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Type)
)'''
create_table_producteur = '''CREATE TABLE Producteur(
   Id_Producteur INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Producteur),
   Producteur VARCHAR(100)
)'''
create_table_realisateur = '''CREATE TABLE Realisateur(
   Id_Realisateur INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Realisateur),
   Prenom_Nom_Realisateur VARCHAR(100)
)'''
create_table_production = '''CREATE TABLE Production(
   Id_Production INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Production),
   Titre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)'''
create_table_Est_de_Type = '''CREATE TABLE Est_de_Type(
   Id_Type INT NOT NULL,
   Id_Production INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Type,Id_Production ),
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_Type) REFERENCES Type_Tournage(Id_Type),
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_Production) REFERENCES Production(Id_Production)
)'''
create_table_tourner = '''CREATE TABLE Tourner(
   Id_Production INT NOT NULL,
   Id_Lieu VARCHAR(100),
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Production, Id_Lieu),
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_Production) REFERENCES Production(Id_Production),
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_Lieu) REFERENCES Tournage(Id_Lieu)
)'''
create_table_realiser = '''CREATE TABLE Realiser(
   Id_Production INT NOT NULL,
   Id_Realisateur INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Production, Id_Realisateur),
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_Production) REFERENCES Production(Id_Production),
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_Realisateur) REFERENCES Realisateur(Id_Realisateur)
)'''
create_table_produire = '''CREATE TABLE Produire(
   Id_Production INT,
   Id_Producteur INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(Id_Production, Id_Producteur),
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_Production) REFERENCES Production(Id_Production),
   FOREIGN KEY(Id_Producteur) REFERENCES Producteur(Id_Producteur)
)'''

cursor.execute(create_table_tournage)
cursor.execute(create_table_producteur)
cursor.execute(create_table_realisateur)
cursor.execute(create_table_production)
cursor.execute(create_table_tourner)
cursor.execute(create_table_realiser)
cursor.execute(create_table_produire)
cursor.execute(create_table_Type_Tournage)
cursor.execute(create_table_Est_de_Type)

liste_producteurs = []
liste_productions = []
liens_film_producteur = []
liste_realisateurs = []
liens_film_realisateur = []
liste_types= []
liens_film_type = []
liste_lieux= []
liste_debut= []
liste_fin= []
liste_localisation= []
liste_CP= []
liste_X= []
liste_Y= []
liste_shape= []
liens_film_tournage = []
tournages=[]
with open('lieux-de-tournage-a-paris.csv', encoding="utf8") as csv_data:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter = ';')
    Id_Tournage = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        Id_Tournage += 1
        if Id_Tournage>0:
            Id_Lieu = row[0]
            Annee = row[1]
            Type_de_tournage = row[2]
            Titre = row[3]
            Prenom_Nom_Realisateur = row[4]
            Producteur = row[5]
            Localisation_de_la_scene = row[6]
            Code_Postal = row[7]
            Date_de_debut = row[8]
            Date_de_debut = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date_de_debut, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
            Date_de_fin = row[9]
            Date_de_fin = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date_de_fin, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
            Coordonnees_en_X = row[10]
            Coordonnees_en_Y = row[11]
            geo_shape = row[12]
            geo_point_2d = row[13]

            if not Producteur in liste_producteurs:
                liste_producteurs.append(Producteur)

            if not Titre in liste_productions:
                liste_productions.append(Titre)

            if not Prenom_Nom_Realisateur in liste_realisateurs:
                liste_realisateurs.append(Prenom_Nom_Realisateur)

            if not Type_de_tournage in liste_types:
                liste_types.append(Type_de_tournage)

            tournage = (Id_Lieu, Date_de_debut, Date_de_fin, Localisation_de_la_scene, Code_Postal,Coordonnees_en_X, Coordonnees_en_Y)
            if not tournage in tournages:
                tournages.append(tournage)

            Id_Producteur = liste_producteurs.index(Producteur)+1
            Id_Production = liste_productions.index(Titre)+1
            Id_Realisateur = liste_realisateurs.index(Prenom_Nom_Realisateur)+1
            Id_Type = liste_types.index(Type_de_tournage)+1
            #Id_Tournage = tournages.index(Id_Lieu, Date_de_debut, Date_de_fin, Localisation_de_la_scene, Code_Postal,Coordonnees_en_X, Coordonnees_en_Y, geo_shape)+1

            lien_film_producteur = (Id_Producteur, Id_Production)
            if not lien_film_producteur in liens_film_producteur:
                liens_film_producteur.append(lien_film_producteur)

            lien_film_realisateur = (Id_Realisateur, Id_Production)
            if not lien_film_realisateur in liens_film_realisateur:
                liens_film_realisateur.append(lien_film_realisateur)

            lien_film_type = (Id_Type, Id_Production)
            if not lien_film_type in liens_film_type:
                liens_film_type.append(lien_film_type)

            lien_film_tournage = (Id_Lieu, Id_Production)
            if not lien_film_tournage in liens_film_tournage:
                liens_film_tournage.append(lien_film_tournage)

sql_producteur = None
for Id_Producteur in range(len(liste_producteurs)):
    Producteur = liste_producteurs[Id_Producteur]
    if Id_Producteur>0:
        sql_producteur = '{}, ("{}")'.format(sql_producteur, Producteur)
    else:
        sql_producteur= '''INSERT INTO Producteur(Producteur) VALUES  ("{}")'''.format(Producteur)
sql_producteur = '{};'.format(sql_producteur)
cursor.execute(sql_producteur)

sql_production = None
for Id_Production in range(len(liste_productions)):
    Titre = liste_productions[Id_Production]
    if Id_Production>0:
        sql_production = '{}, ("{}")'.format(sql_production, Titre)
    else:
        sql_production= '''INSERT INTO Production(Titre) VALUES ("{}")'''.format(Titre)
sql_production = '{};'.format(sql_production)
cursor.execute(sql_production)

sql_realisateur = None
for Id_Realisateur in range(len(liste_realisateurs)):
    Prenom_Nom_Realisateur = liste_realisateurs[Id_Realisateur]

    if Id_Realisateur>0:
        sql_realisateur = '{}, ("{}")'.format(sql_realisateur, Prenom_Nom_Realisateur)
    else:
        sql_realisateur= '''INSERT INTO Realisateur(Prenom_Nom_Realisateur) VALUES ("{}")'''.format(Prenom_Nom_Realisateur)
sql_realisateur = '{};'.format(sql_realisateur)
cursor.execute(sql_realisateur)

sql_type = None
for Id_Type in range(len(liste_types)):
    Type_de_tournage = liste_types[Id_Type]

    if Id_Type>0:
        sql_type = '{}, ("{}")'.format(sql_type, Type_de_tournage)
    else:
        sql_type= '''INSERT INTO Type_Tournage(Types_de_Tournage) VALUES ("{}")'''.format(Type_de_tournage)
sql_type = '{};'.format(sql_type)
cursor.execute(sql_type)

#("{}","{}","{}","{}","{}","{}","{}")

sql_tournage = None
for Id in range(len(tournages)):
    entry = tournages[Id]
    if Id>0:
        sql_tournage = '{},({},{},{},{},{},{},{})'.format(sql_tournage, Id_Lieu, Date_de_debut, Date_de_fin, Localisation_de_la_scene, Code_Postal, Coordonnees_en_X, Coordonnees_en_Y)
    if Id<= 0:
        sql_tournage = '''INSERT INTO Tournage(Id_Lieu, Date_de_debut, Date_de_fin, Localisation_de_la_scene, Code_Postal, Coordonnees_en_X, Coordonnees_en_Y) VALUES("{}")'''.format(entry)
        sql_tournage = buffer_tournage.format(entry)
sql_tournage = '{};'.format(sql_tournage)
print(sql_tournage)
cursor.execute(sql_tournage)

sql_produire = None
for Id in range(len(liens_film_producteur)):
    entry = liens_film_producteur[Id]
    if Id>0:
        sql_produire = '{},({},{})' .format(sql_produire, entry[0], entry[1])
    else:
        sql_produire= '''INSERT INTO Produire(Id_Producteur, Id_Production) VALUES {}'''.format(entry)
sql_produire = '{};'.format(sql_produire)
cursor.execute(sql_produire)

sql_realiser = None
for Id in range(len(liens_film_realisateur)):
    entry = liens_film_realisateur[Id]
    if Id>0:
        sql_realiser = '{},({},{})' .format(sql_realiser, entry[0], entry[1])
    else:
        sql_realiser= '''INSERT INTO Realiser(Id_Realisateur, Id_Production) VALUES {}'''.format(entry)
sql_realiser = '{};'.format(sql_realiser)
cursor.execute(sql_realiser)

sql_estType = None
for Id in range(len(liens_film_type)):
    entry = liens_film_type[Id]
    if Id>0:
        sql_estType = '{},({},{})' .format(sql_estType, entry[0], entry[1])
    else:
        sql_estType= '''INSERT INTO Est_de_Type(Id_Type, Id_Production) VALUES {}'''.format(entry)
sql_estType = '{};'.format(sql_estType)
cursor.execute(sql_estType)


cursor.close()
film.commit()
film.close()
```

When I try to print 'sql_tournage', the .csv file's last row gets printed several times. I'm quite lost right now.

Comment: First problem: Using `format` is **extremely dangerous** due to [SQL injection issues](https://bobby-tables.com). Use the placeholder values feature built into the MySQL driver. Replace *all* of this code with `%s` placeholders and pass a tuple to execute.

Comment: Use cursor.executemany() and pass the data in a list of tuples. Especially if you use MariaDB Connector/Python together with MariaDB Server > 10.2 this is extremely fast for insert/update/replace and delete operations.